# Reduce Speed of Specific agent in the free space model

Tags: events, anylogic, agent

I am creating an event to taking 9 AGVs from total AGVs and reducing the speed in the free space model but its giving error. How could I resolve this issue?
Looking for help and thanks.

[Event of 9 AGVs with different features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyJvD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the `setMaxSpeed()` method on the actual agent you loop through, not on `subsetOfAgents`.

Try `((AGV)a).setMaximumSpeed(0.5);`. This takes your agent `a`, tells AnyLogic that it is actually an AGV and this allows AnyLogic to use the method.

NOTE: Read up on "code complete" in the help. Never type code yourself. With code-complete, it would not let you write this code at all, because it is impossible to execute

Comment: If you find a reply help, please upvote it so other can find it easier in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote